# save pandas df into several different CSV files

Tags: python, pandas

This is some code that will generate some random time series data. Ultimately I am trying to save each days, data into separate CSV files...

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from numpy.random import randint 

np.random.seed(10)  # added for reproductibility                                                                                                                                                                 

rng = pd.date_range('10/9/2018 00:00', periods=1000, freq='1H') 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 100, 1000)}, index=rng)
```

I can print each days data with this:

```
for idx, days in df.groupby(df.index.date):
    print(days)
```

But how could I encorporate savings individual CSV files into a directory `csv` each file named with the first time stamp entry of month & day? (Code below does not work)

```
for idx, days in df.groupby(df.index.date):
    for day in days:
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(day))
        month_num = df.index.month[0]
        day_num = df.index.day[0]

        df2.to_csv('/csv/' + f'{month_num}' + '_' + f'{day_num}' + '.csv')
```

Comment: What does not work? Can you precise the error you face?

Comment: Can you explain why the inner `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate over all available days, filter your dataframe and then save.

```
# iterate over all available days 
for date in set(df.index.date):  

    # filter your dataframe    
    filtered_df = df.loc[df.index.date == date].copy()

    # save it
    filename = date.strftime('%m_%d')  # filename represented as 'month_day'
    filtered_df.to_csv(f"./csv/{filename}.csv")
```

Comment: I have a sub directory created `csv` but when I run the code I get an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/csv/11_06.csv'`

Comment: Can the code be modified to access the sub directory and then save the file to the `filename`?

Comment: I think you meant `./csv/xxx.csv` then? Instead of `/csv/xxx.csv`? Edited.

Comment: That worked thank you so much. What does the `.` do?

Comment: You're welcome! Using `./` for a path means you're starting from your current location. While starting with `/` typically refers to the root directory of your OS e.g. `/etc/`